# Calculating Energy & Small functional time scale

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electricity

I have an electric motor that can apply a pull force of $3000 \;\mathrm{lb}$ (electric winch), it draws $180 \;\mathrm{A}$ at $12 \;\mathrm{V}$.

I understand that power $P = I \cdot V = 2.1 \;\mathrm{kW}$. If I know the time this motor was running I can figure out the energy using $E = P \cdot t$. Why not use the capable force ($3000 \;\mathrm{lb}$) times the applied distance?

In addition, can electric motors function at 100% (fully running) at very short time scales, like 0.001 seconds - 0.020 seconds, using full power?

Comment: There should be some build up time for power I suppose. A motor cannot build up power just like that in a matter of microseconds.

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän Why?

Comment: It would violate some very "special" rules.

Comment: True, what about the formula of converting Power to Energy? Energy(J) = P(W) x t(s), Am I right?

Comment: You are looking at the problem in the classical perspective. Analysing things that appear to occur instantaneously requires relativistic modifications. The formula you have cited is right for classical cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you use force times distance, then you are calculating the output work $W_{out} = Fs$. If you calculate current times voltage times time, then you get the electric input energy $E_{in} = UIt$.

However since no device can have a 100% energy efficiency, it will always be $W_{out} < E_{in}$. It therefore depends what exactly you want to calculate. The energy difference will be released to the environment in form of heat.

I assumed the output force and the current to be constant, which in general will not be the case, especially if you are talking about short time scales. In the general case you have to integrate over the force profile and/or current profile.

The efficiency itself will likely depend on the load on the motor. (as will the output force and the input current)

Comment: What about it's funtionality over 0.001 seconds to 0.020 seconds?

Comment: The speed of the motor cannot jump to maximum instantaneously, so it has to accelerate first. Over this period force/power and energy consumption are not constant. So the calculations are more complex there. How long the build up takes depends on the model used, usually there are data sheets with these details.

Comment: Since everything is constant in the problem, I'm using the formula S = 1/2 at^2 to figure out the time. Is that fine?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Also your last question was not part of the original one. Can you edit the main question with more problem details? For example: What load is on the motor.

Comment: Im going to post a newer question but thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, Energy = P x t correct?

Comment: Yes, if $P$ is constant in time.